# CiviCRM API: How to get event by custom multiselect field option?

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, api

I have an event with a custom field `custom_1` which is a multi select or checkbox list with two options `Category A` and `Category B`:

```
"custom_1": [
  "category A",
  "category B"
],
```

Now I'm trying to get all events which have at least option `category A`:

```
CRM.api3('Event', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "custom_1": "category A"
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

With this request I just get the events, which have `category A`, but not `category B`:

```
"custom_1": [
  "category A"
],
```

But I need all events with `category A`, regardless if they have another category. So events with this custom field values should also be returned:

```
"custom_1": [
  "category A",
  "category B"
],
```

Is it possible to make an API request like "Get all events which have **at least** one of this custom field options."?

Answer (score 2):

I think the feature you need is [A 'contains' operation for the api to search multiselect custom values](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17096), which is work in progress. See the associated [pull request #6612](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6612) for discussion of progress - it seems to have stalled but with good work already having been done.

Answer (score 0):

May be try the below - If the below doesn't help then you need to write a sql for the same I guess

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Event', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => array("custom_13"),
  'custom_13' => array('NOT IN' => array(2, 3)),
));
```

try to set unwanted category in "NOT IN" condition

Thanks - I guess this helps!!!

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstand my issue. It's ok, that the event is in category `2` or `3`, as long it is in `1`.

Comment: did you try to run the same - this is giving you a list of category A from all the set -

Comment: Oh, you seem to be right. But I don't understand why this works. Shouldn't 'NOT IN' exclude all events, that are in `2` or `3`, even though they are in `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Because [#6612](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6612) has been closed I'm currently using `LIKE` as a workaround:

```
CRM.api3('Event', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "custom_1": {"LIKE":"%category A%"}
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

which is working fine if the value is not part of another value. E.g filtering by "*category A*" would also list events of "*category A*wesome".